# A simple fork with an ugly waitpid

Tags: c, child-process, unix

This is my first take on `fork`, `exec` and `waitpid`. I didn't quite understand why I had to use a `while` loop with `waitpid`. I discovered that `waitpid` sets `errno` to `EINTR` which is translated to this:

```
#define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */
```

And I saw a suggestion in [comp.unix.programmer archives](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2005-01/0347.html) to use a `while` loop for `waitpid`.

My implementation works on OSX 10.10.3 but it doesn't quite satisfy me. Can you provide suggestions?

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int exit_status_raw;

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        printerr("Forking failed");
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("CHILD says Hello\n");

        execlp("./child", "./child", NULL);

        printerr("exec failed");
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        printf("PARENT says Hello\n");

        while ((pid = waitpid(pid, &exit_status_raw, 0)) == -1) {
            switch (errno) {
                case EINTR:
                    printerr("waitpid failed with EINTR. Retrying...");
                    continue;
                default:
                    printerr("waitpid failed");
                    break;
            }
        }

        printf("Child exited with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(exit_status_raw));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**child.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("This is a time consuming computation\n");
    // ...
    printerr("Sorry. I failed to compute");
    return 127;
}
```

**common.h**

```
#ifndef my_common_h
#define my_common_h

void printerr(const char *message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
}

#endif
```

Comment: I've found an explanation on why certain blocking system calls are `EINTR`upttible in this blog post: [EINTR and What It Is Good For](http://250bpm.com/blog:12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I didn't quite understand why I had to use a while loop with waitpid

To loop or not to loop should be a well-thought design decision.

The main reason for `wait`ing in the loop is to monitor child's life for events other than exit (e.g. when the `WUNTRACED` option is set). Since you do not set this option, the only remaining reason is to deal with interrupts. It is really a minor one, and often you *want* to be interrupted (consider for example a child entering a non-alertable sleep).

The way you are dealing with errors other than `EINTR` is not correct. `break` only breaks the `switch`, and the code keeps executing the loop. Since the errors like `EINVAL` are non-recoverable, the program would get stuck in the loop forever (hitting the same error over and over again).

Comment: In the end, I had to embrace the `while` loop. Here's a very informative blog post from the author of ZeroMQ about this http://250bpm.com/blog:12

Answer (score 5):

- You could consider terminating with the exit codes from [`<sysexits.h>`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.3-RELEASE&format=html), especially if the client is expecting them.  For instance, if `fork()` fails, `return` or call `exit()` with `EX_OSERR`.
- It may be helpful to make the `127` error code a macro with a relevant name, since it's probably not a very commonly-known error code, especially returned from `main()`.  I assume it's being used correctly (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)).
- It would look clearer to put `execlp()`'s return value in a conditional, rather than always printing an error afterwards.  Since the `exec` functions only return a value (-1) on error, have the error message displayed only if this value gets returned.  Of course, have `errno` printed out as well.
- You should also check to see if the child process has terminated from a signal.  This can be done by calling `WTERMSIG()` and displaying its returned signal value.  *That* can be determined by first checking the return value of `WIFEXITED()` (before doing the other checks).

  Example:

  ```
  int status;

  // do checks with waitpid()

  if (WIFEXITED(status))
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "the process exited with code %d\n", status);   
      exit(WEXITSTATUS(status));
  }
  else
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "the process died with signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
      exit(EX_OSERR);
  }
  ```
- I don't see a need for `printerr()` when you can just use [`perror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), which is already provided in `<stdio.h>` and does more than your function.  Regardless, it's a little redundant to put "failed" into the argument.  Clients receiving such a message should already be able to see that it's some kind of error, *and* it's automatically printed to `stderr`.
- Instead of just having `default` provide an ambiguous error message, have it display the current value of `errno` with `perror()`.  Again, your function doesn't do very much.

Comment: I didn't know about the `perror`. And thank you for reminding `sysexits.h`. The case of failing `waitpid` is the actual thing that bothers me.